# how can i handle compare-object result?

Tags: powershell

I made a lot of searches before posting with no luck.
Let's suppose I want to compare two folders

```
compare-object @(gci c:\folder1) @(gci c:\folder2)
```

I see the output with sideIndicator and so on but how can I do something like

```
if objects are equals then
  do something
else
  do something else
end if
```

if I pipe this cmdlet to get-member I see an equals method but I don't know how to use it and I'm not even sure if it could solve my problem. Is there any boolean property that tells me if objects are equals or not?
Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

Hi my saviour. :)
If I have understood I had to do something like this:

```
$differences = 0
$a = @(1,4,5,3)
$b = @(1,3,4)
diff $a $b -in | % {if($_.sideindicator -ne "==") {$differences+=1}}
write-host $differences
```

Is this the only way?

**EDIT 2.**

It seems to me that if I don't use -includeEqual I get only the differences, so this code suffices.

```
$differences = 0
$a = @(1,4,5,3)
$b = @(1,3,4)
diff $a $b  | % {$differences+=1}
write-host $differences
```

and it returns 0 if objects are equals. Is it the right way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, you don't need to count the differences, instead if just finding '==' is enough for you, you might use:

```
$a = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
$b = @(10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
if (diff $a $b) { 
 'not equal'
} else {
 'equal'
}
```

How it works: if the pipeline (~sequence from diff) returns collection of 0 items, then when converting to `[bool]`, it is converted to `$false`. Nonempty collection is converted to `$true`.

Comment: Hi stej. Thank you veru much. Now I see :)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this example:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/archive/2011/01/12/quicktip-Comparing-installed-HotFixes-on-a-two-node-Cluster.aspx

You can use the sideindicator value and do a string compare.

Comment: Thanks for your costant support. Bye. ;)

Comment: Oops, sorry. Was asleep when all other disucssion happened. Time zones you see!

Comment: No problem. You're always very kind with me. Now I go to sleep too. ;)

Comment: Sorry.. just answered a question, didn't check your solution if it is close or not. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a count of the differences, you can get even more succinct:

```
$a = 1..10
$b = 3..11
(diff $a $b).count
```